# Groovy property not recognized in ElasticSearch Watcher Transform Script getting proper JSON

Tags: json, elasticsearch, groovy

I'm using:

- Elasticsearch 2.3
- Watcher
- Topbeat

The goal is to create a watch that every x amount of time does a query and retrieves some hits, and post it to a web server. This works fine. However, the Json response in {{ctx.payload.hits.hits}} isn't Json, so I can't proccess it. The same issue seems to appear in some threads, this being the most similar to [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166043/elasticsearch-watcher-transform-script):

So, this is my watch (the input works fine, the issue is in the script of the action):

```
PUT _watcher/watch/running_process_watch
{
  "trigger" : {
      "schedule" : {
        "interval" : "10s"
    }
  },
  "input" : {... },
  "actions" : {
    "ping_webhook": {
        "transform":{
        "script": "return [ body: groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(ctx.payload.hits.hits)]"
          },
          "webhook": {
            "method": "POST",
            "host":   "localhost",
            "port":   4567,
            "path":   "/register_data",
            "headers": {
             "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            "body" : "data: {{ctx.payload.body}}"
          }
        }
  }
}
```

The error:

```
failed to execute [script] transform for [running_process_watch_0-2016-06-08T17:25:14.162Z]
ScriptException[failed to run inline script [return [ body: groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(ctx.payload.hits.hits)]] using lang [groovy]]; nested: MissingPropertyException[No such property: groovy for class: 1605d064acb49c10c464b655dacc9193f4e2e484];
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:320)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.transform.script.ExecutableScriptTransform.doExecute(ExecutableScriptTransform.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.transform.script.ExecutableScriptTransform.execute(ExecutableScriptTransform.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.transform.script.ExecutableScriptTransform.execute(ExecutableScriptTransform.java:41)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.actions.ActionWrapper.execute(ActionWrapper.java:94)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.execution.ExecutionService.executeInner(ExecutionService.java:388)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.execution.ExecutionService.execute(ExecutionService.java:273)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.execution.ExecutionService$WatchExecutionTask.run(ExecutionService.java:438)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea to make groovy.json usable inside the watcher action script? Or any other idea to return proper json from the ctx.hits.hits?

Answer (score 0):

So, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18898) in Elasticsearch repo. After some discussion, a native toJson function is going to be implemented in the mustache templating engine so it renders json by default.

[Here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/18856) is the pull request.

Hopefully in the next release will be ready.